# How to show scroll bar in a div

Tags: css, electron

I've this css in my div but the scroll bar does not show up when needed, I can scroll the div but without scrollbar, how can I solve it? This problem only happens on electron

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 530px;
  color: black;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

Comment: Try reducing the height of the of the container.

Comment: Not electron specific at all..

Answer (score 1):

is there any content in the div? To make it scrollable the height of the div needs to be less than the height of the content.

So either add more content or **reduce the height of the div** like I have below.

```css
.container {
  width: 350px;
  height: 100px;
  color: black;
  overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam est est, congue nec accumsan quis, volutpat eleifend sapien. Nunc metus augue, ultrices at lectus ut, molestie venenatis orci. Phasellus eu libero id sapien pharetra pulvinar. Vestibulum ut porta leo, sed ornare lorem. Phasellus sollicitudin ligula id nibh dictum, non lacinia turpis luctus. Nulla mi quam, blandit at faucibus sed, aliquam quis libero. Nullam placerat nisl est, at efficitur orci aliquet vel. 
</p>
</div>
```